# Jquery datesDisabled on datepicker does not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-datepicker

I know there is a lot of subject on it but after several days on the problem I decide to post.
I need to disable dates in my bootstrap datepicker here is the html code:

```
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../Css/css.css">
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

```
<input type="text"  class="form-control" id="txt_dateDebut" value="<?php 
    echo $uneLocation->getDateDebut(); ?>" name="txt_dateDebut" required>
```

So I tried lot of solution in Jquery but nothing happens, here is one :

```
    //disable these dates
var datesForDisable = ["25-01-2019", "26-01-2019", "27-01-2019"];

$("#txt_dateDebut").datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    autoclose: true,
    weekStart: 1,
    calendarWeeks: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        //format date in datepicker to dd-mm-yy
        var date1 = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
        //disable dates
        return [ datesForDisable.indexOf(date1) == -1 ]
    }
});
```

(Once the test is done successfully the goal is to dynamically fill in PHP the table of dates to disable )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [beforeShowDay](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) of datepicker to disable the dates .i.e :

```js
//disable these dates
var datesForDisable = ["25.01.2019", "26.01.2019", "27.01.2019"]

$("#txt_dateDebut").datepicker({
      format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
      autoclose: true,
      weekStart: 1,
      calendarWeeks: true,
      todayHighlight: true,
      beforeShowDay: function(date){
       //format date in datepicker to dd-mm-yy
        var date1 = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', date);
        //disable dates
        return [ datesForDisable.indexOf(date1) == -1 ]
       }
      });
```

```html
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input  type="text" class="form-control" id="txt_dateDebut" value="<?php echo $uneLocation->getDateDebut(); ?>" name="txt_dateDebut" required>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help but it does not work the dates can be selected... 
I saw that you had modified the type of the input in text, with the jquery it is supposed to turn it into datepicker? because personally it's just a text field if I put "type =" text "

Comment: go on this -> `25-01-2019` date and check if it is disable or not in above answer ,also click on `input` box datepicker will get open , and whatever date you will select will be display in that textbox.

Comment: I can't open datepicker, it's textbox text when I click on it I have this error in the console : "Cannot read property 'formatDate' of undefined" sry I begin in jquery...

Comment: did you add required `scripts` in your code ,can you edit your question with changes you made in your code, so that it would be easy to understand,also check my edited answer.

Comment: I have run your updated code , it is working fine , i didn't got any error .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap datepicker use ,

```
$('.#txt_dateDebut').datepicker({
beforeShowDay:function(Date){
var curr_date = Date.getDate();
var curr_month = Date.getMonth()+1;
var curr_year = Date.getFullYear();        
var curr_date=curr_month+'/'+curr_date+'/'+curr_year;        

if (datesForDisable.indexOf(curr_date)>-1) return false;        
}
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help but it does not work too... I begin in jquery maybe the problem is minor ...